# Idea is using different version of library than defined in project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project opened in IntelliJ Idea. Maven build(executed from IDE) works fine, but when I try to run the some JUnit test, it shows me some import issues, because some older version of one library is used. The library is called `sf-gml-api` and the desired version is `1.50.3`, but in the External Libraries node in the project, idea shows this:

[image: External Libraries]

The obvious thing to check is if some other library doesn't depend on this version, but `mvn dependency:tree` seems to be in order - correct version everywhere.

```
> mvn dependency:tree | grep sf-gml-api
[INFO] +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |     +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.snowflakesoft.common:sf-gml-api:jar:1.50.3:compile
```

I've tried `maven reimport` in Idea, but without any luck. What could be the issue? The dependencies are only defined in the pom files.

- IntelliJ Idea 14.1.4
- Maven 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Clearing `~/.IntelliJIdea14/system/Maven` didn't help as well as invalidating caches and restart.

What fixed the problem was installing Idea update 2016.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you delete it from Open Module Settings -> libraries and refresh workspace. If It still persists try to analyze this library by intellij with right click on library and Analazy -> Analyze dependencies.